# Script to change animation play state

Tags: javascript, html, css

If i put some script in HTML file to change the animation play state,it's works.But when i put the script in a script file,it's not working.Can anyone tell me why?
script like this:

```
var buttons=document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++) {
    console.log(buttons.length);
    buttons[i].onclick=function(e) {
      document.getElementById("para")
      .style.WebkitAnimationPlayState=e.target.innerHTML;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The elements may not be defined in `document`. Try placing the existing script within `load` event handler of `window`

```
function toggleAnimationPlayState() {
  var buttons=document.getElementsByTagName("button");
  for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++) {
    console.log(buttons.length);
    buttons[i].onclick=function(e) {
      document.getElementById("para")
      .style.WebkitAnimationPlayState=e.target.innerHTML;
    };
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", toggleAnimationPlayState);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script dependens on the existing of this Button :

```
=document.getElementsByTagName("button");
```

So,

- **it works** because the script has been running after rendering the button .
- **It does not work** because either :

  - Fail to import script. (check browser's console)

OR

- Import the script BEFORE rendering the button .

#### Solution :

- follow this order .

  ```
    <button>....</button>
       .......
    <script src="/uri/of/script.js"></script>
  ```

  - OR, run your code inside `onload` listner of `window`